# Averaging the result of a subquery in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a query that searches through a Medicare database listing how much doctors charge for various procedures.

Ideally, this query would:

- Return every record, meaning every procedure for every doctor. (I'll add filtering `WHERE` clauses later)
- Return the average amount doctors charge for each procedure
- Return the percentage difference between the average cost and what each individual doctor charges
- Return the average of all those percentage differences for each doctor, generating a meta cost-differential score.

With the query below, I've been able to achieve everything but the last goal.

```
SELECT medicare.*, 
       peerAverage.average AS charge_average, 
       ( medicare.average_submitted_chrg_amt - peerAverage.average ) / 
       peerAverage.average * 100 AS difference_from_average,
       Avg( ( medicare.average_submitted_chrg_amt - peerAverage.average ) / 
       peerAverage.average * 100 ) as total_difference_from_average
FROM   medicare 
       JOIN (SELECT Avg(average_submitted_chrg_amt) AS average, 
                    procedure_code 
             FROM   medicare 
             GROUP  BY procedure_code) AS peerAverage 
         ON medicare.procedure_code = peerAverage.procedure_code 
ORDER  BY procedure_code ASC, 
          difference_from_average DESC
```

When I add the final `SELECT` condition (`Avg( ( medicare.average_submitted_chrg_amt - peerAverage.average ) / peerAverage.average * 100 ) as total_difference_from_average`), the query only returns one record.

Delete that condition and the query returns the correct number of records. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation functions move the aggregation level up. Until you have specified the grouping conditions for the average function, it will always return one row aggregated over all values, returned by the expression

Comment: Ah. So adding a `GROUP BY doctor_name` or some other unique key in the outer query should clear things up?